# Problem reading a stdin as file in a structured list in C

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-management, linked-list

Basicaly what i want is to read a file in these case im using the stdin as my file `FILE *f=stdin;`

the files contains something like these

`2019 - Frog and Mouse
1982 - Water and gelly
3025 - Sugar
...`

I want to be able to read and print the names and the total  number of characters of the names

so far i have created a structure and a list

```
typedef struct struct_data_uc{
    int *uc_number;
    char *uc_name;
} S_data_uc;

typedef struct List_uc_data{
    S_data_uc uc_data;
    struct List_uc_data *next;
} L_uc_data;

L_uc_data* UC_add(L_uc_data *list, L_uc_data data_uc){
    L_uc_data *new;
    new=(L_uc_data*)malloc(sizeof(L_uc_data));
    if(new!=NULL){
        (*new)=data_uc;
        new->next=list;
        return new;
    }
    return list;
}
```

then i created the functions to read the list and show the results and also ree the list

```
void UC_free(L_uc_data *list){
    L_uc_data *aux;
    while(list!=NULL){
        aux=list->next;
        free(list);
        list=aux;
    }
}

void UC_read(L_uc_data *data_uc, FILE *fin, FILE *fout){
    char str[MAXSTR];
    if(fout!=NULL)
        fscanf(fin,"%d - %c",&data_uc->uc_data.uc_number,&data_uc->uc_data.uc_name);

void UC_Show(L_uc_data *data_uc, FILE *fout, int prompt){
    if(prompt==0){
        fprintf(fout,"%d - %c\n",
        data_uc->uc_data.uc_number,
        data_uc->uc_data.uc_name);
    }else{
        fprintf(fout,"%d - %c\n",
        data_uc->uc_data.uc_number,
        data_uc->uc_data.uc_name);
        }
}
```

than my main

```
int main(){

FILE *f=stdin;
L_uc_data *list=NULL, *i, data_uc;

UC_read(&data_uc, stdin, stdout);
list=UC_add(list,data_uc);

for(i=list;i!=NULL;i=i->next)
    UC_Show(i,f,0);

    return 0;
}
```

but the program wont seems to work, any help?

Comment: Have a look at [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

Comment: `fscanf(fin,"%d - %c",&data_uc->uc_data.uc_number,&data_uc->uc_data.uc_name);` you need to allocate memory to `uc_number` and `uc_name`.

Comment: and `(*new)=data_uc;` because of pointers involved you should make deep copy.

Comment: `int *uc_number;` You probably don't need that to be a pointer: `int uc_number;` Also, in `scanf`, `printf`, [et al](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), `%c` is the code for a single `char`. To print/scan a string use `%s`.

Comment: What's the point of using a pointer-to-int instead of a plain int as the type of `uc_number` in the definition of `struct struct_data_uc` ?

Comment: You should always check the value returned by `scanf`.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `stdin` for output?  You should write to `stdout`

Comment: If you check the value returned by `printf`, you will probably see that it is negative, and that errno has been set to EBADF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite a few errors in your code. I've tried to fix without modifying the original code too much. See the comments for details.

```
typedef struct struct_data_uc{
    int uc_number;   // Changed from int *
    char *uc_name;
} S_data_uc;

typedef struct List_uc_data{
    S_data_uc uc_data;
    struct List_uc_data *next;
} L_uc_data;

// Allocate a new L_uc_data and insert into list
L_uc_data* UC_add(L_uc_data *list, int number, const char *name)
{
    L_uc_data *new = malloc(sizeof(L_uc_data));
    if (new != NULL) {
        new->uc_data.uc_number = number;
        // Need strdup here to alloc mem and copy
        new->uc_data.uc_name = strdup(name);
        new->next = list;
        return new;
    }
    return list;
}

// Free the entire list
void UC_free(L_uc_data *list)
{
    while (list) {
        L_uc_data *aux = list->next;
        // Free the mem from strdup
        free(list->uc_data.uc_name);
        free(list);
        list = aux;
    }
}

// Reads the entire file and returns a new list
L_uc_data * UC_read(FILE *f)
{
    char line[MAXSTR];
    L_uc_data *the_list = NULL;
    // Using fgets to get the entire line, then sscanf to parse
    while (fgets(line, MAXSTR, f)) {
        int number;
        char name[MAXSTR];
        // Remember to check the return from sscanf
         if (2 == sscanf(line, "%d - %[^\n]", &number, name)) {
            // Add to list
            the_list = UC_add(the_list, number, name);
        }
    }
    return the_list;
}

// Print the entire list
void UC_show(L_uc_data *list, FILE *fout)
{
    while (list) {
        fprintf(fout, "%d - %s\n", list->uc_data.uc_number, list->uc_data.uc_name);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    L_uc_data *list = UC_read(stdin);
    UC_show(list, stdout);
    UC_free(list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it looks good but my output is showing incomplete

`21002 - My input
21010 - The input
Your Output (stdout)
21010 - My
21002 - The`

Comment: also your stdout is missing the last words

Comment: for example on Frog and Mouse is showing only Frog on stdout

Comment: @RGO Ok. Fixed. Will scan from the dash to the newline. https://ideone.com/x9yml2

Answer (score 0):

You're making (at least) 2 mistakes.  First, you are passing `stdin` as the argument to UC_Show, where an attempt is made to write to it.  2nd, you are not checking the value returned by printf, which is almost certainly going to indicate an error and set errno to `EBADF` to tell you exactly what the error is.  You cannot write to stdin.